# Какой глагол подходит? Подобрать глагол

Tags: семантика

Как описать появление первых перьев у птицы, они проклюнулись? прорезались? или другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В книгах находится "пробились". Пример (Труды Арктического НИИ, Ленинград):

> 5 августа опять был добыт гусёнок А. albifrons размером с шилохвость,
> ещё пуховый, но на боках и плечах у него уже **пробились** перья.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=19YhAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA37&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U2B_Bu_VHkcWC-YH5UQobwBz8s6Ew&edge=0

В худ. литературе встречается "*проросли*".

Comment: Alex_ander, важен контекст. В вашей цитате нужно было подчеркнуть, что перья были едва заметны, и не всегда в таком подчёркивании есть нужда. Если хотите, можно обсудить «проросли перья» в контексте употребления.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы о появлении первых перев так и написал: «появились».